# How to prevent all domain names except one domain?

Tags: dns, vpn, websites

I have a server that my users connect to for internet browsing. I want my users can only access a website like domain.com but nothing else.
This website is behind Cloudflare CDN. So I can't block the website based on IP address

Comment: Just put your domain.com into /etc/hosts and turn off other DNS.

Comment: the domain is behind CDN so I don't have the server IP address. what should I write in front of the domain name instead of the IP address in /etc/hosts? @ubfan1